# What resources are available for Spring Integration best practices

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I'm working on a project where we're working with both Spring Integration & AMQP for the first time.

I'm noticing there appears to be a *lot* of XML configuration involved in wiring everything together.  Our config files are already very messy, and it's getting tricky to keep across how everything is hanging together.  I'm worried we're about to make some preventable mistakes.

What resources are available that provide guidance on how to structure large-scale, real-world spring integration & AMQP projects.

eg:

- What naming conventions should we follow for channels / queues / exchanges
- When to employ XML config vs Annotation based config
- Is it ok to mix & match annotations & xml, or is this a recipe for disaster?
- How to layout the bean definitions for ease of use

Note - I'm not looking for guidance on what the various components do, more - how to structure your project to foster maintainability.

Ideally, I'm looking for:

- Blog posts
- Books
- StackOverflow answers (answers inline would be great, too)

Answer (score 0):

It is not SI and AMQP specific but, I think reading
[Enterprise Integration Patterns : Designing, Building, and Deploying Messaging Solutions](http://amazon.com/o/asin/0321200683/ref=nosim/enterpriseint-20) by  would be very helpful. Also this [link](http://www.eaipatterns.com/) has also good resources.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can view this [Spring Integration Practical Tips and Tricks](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Spring-Integration-Practical-Tips-and-Tricks) video.